# Listar objetos por bairros

Tags: android, firebase

Possuo um objeto onde é possível adicionar uma lista de endereços no campo endereço, o objetivo é listar os objetos de acordo com os os bairros onde os objetos residem.

Objeto:

```
public class Suspeito implements Serializable {

private String id;
private String foto;
private String nome;
private String apelido;
private String data_nascimento;
private String num_documento;
private String tipo_documento;
private String mae;
private String pai;
private String antecedentes;
private ArrayList<Endereco> endereco;
private String anotacoes;
}
```

Query:

```
 consulta = firebaseReferencia.child("Suspeitos").child("endereco")
                .orderByChild("bairro")
                .equalTo(txt_bairro.getText().toString().toUpperCase());
```

A consulta está retornando null.

Objeto JSON firebase:
[image: firebase]

Comment: Experimente `.child("Suspeitos").orderByChild("endereco/bairro")`

Comment: Tentei `.child("Suspeitos").orderByChild("endereco/0/bairro")` e retorna os resultados esperados com base nesse nó, no entanto como poderei verificar os demais nós de endereço?